# React-Router-Dom 6.9.0 redirect() doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router-dom

I have issue with redirect() in  RRD.
I want to have redirect to login page if **isLoggedIn = false** in **requireAuth()** func. But I'm getting the result on the attached picture.

Documentation: [reactrouter.com](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect)

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "router",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "miragejs": "^0.1.46",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
}
```

**requireAuth() func**

```
import { redirect } from "react-router-dom"

export async function requireAuth() {
    const isLoggedIn = false

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
        throw redirect("/login")
    }
}
```

**App.tsx with Routes**

```
import HostVans, {loader as hostVansLoader} from "./Pages/Host/HostVans";
import HostVanDetail, {loader as hostVanDetailLoader} from "./Pages/Host/HostVanDetail";
import {requireAuth} from "../utils";

const router = createBrowserRouter(createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route path='/' element={<Layout/>}>
        <Route path='*' element={<Error />}/>
        <Route index element={<Home/>}/>
        <Route path='about' element={<About/>}/>
        <Route path='login' element={<Login/>}/>
        <Route path='vans' element={<Vans/>} loader={vansLoader} errorElement={<Error/>}/>
        <Route path='vans/:id' element={<VanDetail/>} loader={vanDetailLoader}/>
        <Route path='host' element={<HostLayout />}>

            // requireAuth() should redirect to login page, but it doesn't
            <Route index element={<Dashboard />} loader={async () => await requireAuth()}/>


            <Route path="income" element={<Income />}  loader={async () => {
                return null
            }}/>
            <Route path="vans" element={<HostVans/>}  loader={hostVansLoader}/>
            <Route path="vans/:id" element={<HostVanDetail/>}  loader={hostVanDetailLoader}>
                <Route index element={<HostVanInfo/>} loader={async () => {
                    return null
                }}/>
                <Route path="photos" element={<HostVanPhotos/>} loader={async () => {
                    return null
                }}/>
                <Route path="pricing" element={<HostVanPricing/>} loader={async () => {
                    return null
                }}/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="reviews" element={<Reviews />} />
        </Route>

    </Route>
))


const App = () => {
    return (
        <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    )
}

export default App
```

IMG with the problem in browser
[image]

I've tried to put func inside the loader, I've used new Response() from documentation. But it still doesn/t woek

Comment: Try passing `requireAuth` directly ***as*** the loader function, and return the redirect instead of throwing it.

Comment: Is this code part of some online course or tutorial? This is the third or forth time I've seen questions specific to `react-router-dom@6` data routers, redirects, and van rental APIs.

Comment: Actually, the code you have appears to function correctly. Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-6-9-0-redirect-doesnt-work-gkvbk5) with your code copy/pasted in and the loader function redirects user to `"/login"` as you seem to be expecting. See if you can fork the sandbox and add more of your *actual* code in to see if you can create a running, reproducible demo that we could inspect live.

Comment: @Drew Reese It's Scrimba React Router 6 course.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Changed RRD to v6.4.3
Now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, you are getting that error cause `Miragejs` is not compatible with the latest RRD version

```js
import {redirect} from 'react-router'

export async function requireAuth() {
 const isLoggedIn = false

 if (!isLoggedIn) {
  const response = redirect('/login')
  response.body = true
  throw response
 }
 return null
}
```